# Insert an object in the list in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of class objects `UserData`. I get an object from this list through `where` method

```
UserData.Where(s => s.ID == IDKey).ToList(); //ID is unique
```

I would like to make some changes in the object and insert at the same location in the list. However, I donot have the index of this object.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to reinsert it you are working on it directly in the list anyway...

Comment: No, I get an object from this list. I am not working on the list itself. I would like to remove/insert or update that object

Comment: Yes but the object you have is a reference to the one in the list so by updating the object you have found by .Where you are automatically updating the one in the list...

Comment: What types does `UserData` contain? Are they a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Its a List of Class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your getting the item from a LIST its an reference type, if your updating anything to it then it will automatically change the values in LIST. Please check your self after updating...........

Item whichever your getting from

```
UserData.Where(s => s.ID == IDKey).ToList();
```

is an reference type.

Comment: Its a reference type, not an instance ? Vow.. That makes it easy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You can get the index using the method
`UserData.FindIndex(s => s.ID == IDKey)`
It will return an int.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `UserData` is reference type, the list only holds references to instances of that object. So you can change its properties without the need of remove/insert (and obviously do not need index of that object).

I also suggest you want to use `Single` method (instead of `ToList()`) as long as the id is unique.

**Example**

```
public void ChangeUserName(List<UserData> users, int userId, string newName)
{
     var user = users.Single(x=> x.UserId == userId);
     user.Name = newName;  // here you are changing the Name value of UserData objects, which is still part of the list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just fetch the object using `SingleOrDefault` and make related changes; you do not need to add it to the list again; you are simply changing the same instance which is an element of the list.

```
var temp = UserData.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == IDKey);
// apply changes
temp.X = someValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm misunderstanding you then please correct me, but I think you're saying that you essentially want to iterate through the elements of a list, and if it matches a condition then you want to alter it in some way and add it to another list.

If that's the case, then please see the code below to see how to write an anonymous method using the Where clause. The Where clause just wants an anonymous function or delegate which matches the following:

parameters: ElementType element, int index -- return: bool result

which allows it to either select or ignore the element based upon the boolean return. This allows us to submit a simple boolean expression, or a more complex function which has additional steps, as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int IDKey = 1;
            List<SomeClass> UserData = new List<SomeClass>()
            {
                new SomeClass(),
                new SomeClass(1),
                new SomeClass(2)
            };
            //This operation actually works by evaluating the condition provided and adding the
            //object s if the bool returned is true, but we can do other things too
            UserData.Where(s => s.ID == IDKey).ToList();
            //We can actually write an entire method inside the Where clause, like so:
            List<SomeClass> filteredList = UserData.Where((s) => //Create a parameter for the func<SomeClass,bool> by using (varName)
                {
                    bool theBooleanThatActuallyGetsReturnedInTheAboveVersion =
                        (s.ID == IDKey);
                    if (theBooleanThatActuallyGetsReturnedInTheAboveVersion) s.name = "Changed";
                    return theBooleanThatActuallyGetsReturnedInTheAboveVersion;
                }
            ).ToList();

            foreach (SomeClass item in filteredList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.name);
            }
        }
    }
    class SomeClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public SomeClass(int id = 0, string name = "defaultName")
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```